# Training the algorithm for better image recognition

Tags: machine-learning, image-recognition

This is a research question not a direct programming question.

I am working on a symbol recognition algorithm, What the software currently does, it takes an image, divide it into contours (blobs) and start matching each contour with a list of predefined templates. Then for each contour it takes the one that has the highest match rate.

The algorithm is doing fairely however I need to train it better. What I mean is this:
I want to use a machine learning algorithm that will train the algorithm to have better matching. So lets take an example:

I run the recognition on a symbol, the algorithm will run and find that this symbol is a car, then I have to confirm that result (maybe by clicking on "Yes" or "No") the algorithm should learn from that. So if I click on NO the algorithm should learn that this is not a car and will have better result next time (maybe try to match something else). while if i click on YES he will know that he was correct and next time he will perform better when searching for a car.

This is the concept I am trying to research. I need documents or algorithm that can achieve this sort of things. I am not looking for implementations or programming, just concept or researches.

I have done many researches and read a lot about machine learning, neural networks, decision trees.... but i was not able to know how can I use any in my scenarion.

I hope I was clear and this type of question is allowed on stack overflow. if not I'm sorry

Thanks a lot for any help or tip

Comment: If you want to learn about machine learning I would advise investing in college degree, or at the very least getting a good book on the subject.

Comment: If you don't get any joy here, try some of the other stackexchange sites, which may be more helpful at a conceptual level.

Comment: PS - try [Bayesian probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_probability) as a starting point. I've seen it work very well in the past.

Comment: I agree with nickhar. I was drawn here because I was hoping to find some theories :)

Comment: @nickhar Which Stack exchange site would you recommend? thanks

Comment: How is the initial set of templates formed in your case? One straightforward method is to add any new contour confirmed as a car to templates for car. Also you can add "negatives" to a set of templates under the label (semantics) "not a car", and then combine probabilities of "looking like car" and "not looking like car".

Answer (score 5):

Image recognition is still a challenge in the community. What you described in your process of manually clicking yes/no is just creating labeled data. Since this is a very broad area, I will just point you to a few links that might be useful.

- To get start, you might want to use some existing image databases instead of creating your own, which saves you a lot of effort. e.g., this car dataset in [UCIC image db](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/Data/Car/).
- Since you already have the background of machine learning, you can take a look at some survey paper that exactly match your project interests, e.g., search `object recognition survey paper` or `feature extraction car` in google.
- Then you can dive into some good papers and see whether they are suitable for your project. For example, you can check the two papers below that linked with the UCIC image db.

  - Shivani Agarwal, Aatif Awan, and Dan Roth, 
    Learning to detect objects in images via a sparse, part-based representation. 
    IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence, 26(11):1475-1490, 2004.
  - Shivani Agarwal and Dan Roth, 
    Learning a sparse representation for object detection. 
    In Proceedings of the Seventh European Conference on Computer Vision, Part IV, pages 113-130, Copenhagen, Denmark, 2002.
- Also check for some implemented softwares instead of starting from scratch, in your case, [opencv](http://opencv.org/) should be good one to start with.
- For image recognition, feature extraction is one of the most important step. You might want to check some stat-of-the-art algorithms in the community. (SIFT, mean-shift, harr features etc).
- Boosting algorithm might also be useful when you reach the classification step. I see a lot of scholars mention this in image recognition community.
- As @nickbar suggest, discuss more at https://stats.stackexchange.com/